# On special normal subgroup of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for any $x\in G$ we have $x^2\in H$.  prove that  $H$ is normal in $G$.

I think this true, but can not prove it. for example this is true for $$D_8 = <a,b \space | a^4=b^2=1, \space ab = ba^{-1}>$$

Comment: I think this true, but can not prove it. for example this is true for $G=D_{8}=<a,b|a^4=b^2=1, ab=ba^{-1}$ and $H=<a>$.

Comment: you should edit your question to include that information :) I do believe this is a true result as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with the derived (or commutator) subgroup?

Comment: Where did you come across this btw (it is indeed true, and it is one of the exercises in a set I made once, but there I included in as part of a larger exercise that made it a lot easier).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x\in G$ and $h\in H$. We have that $xhx^{-1}=x^2(x^{-1}h)^2h^{-1}$ which belongs to $H$ since $H$ is a subgroup and the given hypothesis.

Comment: Great answer, nice and elementary (as my comment on the question indicates, there is a more advanced way to see it, but this is really neat).

Comment: Put it anyways, that expression took me a while to find btw.

Comment: Done. I suppose that indicates how one might "guess" that it is true.

Answer (score 3):

Zero has already posted a nice and elementary answer, but here is another way to see this, which also indicates how one might "guess" that it is true (without which one would probably not try enough to come up with the expression in his answer).

We will need a few basic results that make for good exercises themselves.

1. If $S$ is a subset of $G$ which is closed under conjugation, then $\langle S\rangle$ (i.e. the subgroup generated by $S$) is normal in $G$.
2. The set of squares in $G$ is closed under conjugation.
3. If $S$ is the set of squares in $G$ and $K = \langle S\rangle$ then $G/K$ is abelian.
4. Any subgroup containing $K$ is normal.
5. If a subgroup contains all squares, then it contains $K$. In particular, $H$ contains $K$ and is thus normal.

Comment: thank you for your explanations

Answer (score 1):

Following @zero, apparently every element of $G/H$ has order at most $2$. This means $G' \subseteq H$ and $G/H \cong C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$ (this could be an empty product, since $H$ could equal $G$).

Comment: And indeed Zero's answer indicates how one can write any commutator as a product of squares.